# Problem with jquery closest() and addClass()

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck right now, and I would appreciate any help. I have this form inside a Bootstrap modal:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="UserForm" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iUserName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iUserName" id="iUserName" placeholder="User Name" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="iPassword" id="iPassword" placeholder="iPassword" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iConfPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="iConfPassword" id="iConfPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iRoleSelect" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Role</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select class="form-control select2" id="iRoleSelect" name="iRoleSelect" style="width: 100%;"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is my JS:

```
$('#UserForm').on('submit', function () {
        var flag_UserName, flag_Password, flag_Role
        var emptyInput = $('#UserForm').find('input[type=text], input[type=password], select').val('')
        for (var i = 0; i < emptyInput.length; i++) {
            var div = emptyInput[i].closest('.form-group').addClass('has-warning')
            console.log(div)
            return false;
        }
    })
```

What I'm trying to do is to find every empty input inside the form, and then add a new 'has-warning' class to the closest div from that input.  My current code is giving me this error:

> `TypeError: emptyInput[i].closest(...).addClass is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you try to do like this

```js
$('#UserForm').on('submit', function () {      
      var flag_UserName, flag_Password, flag_Role   
      var emptyInput = $('#UserForm').find('input[type=text], input[type=password], select');
 
      for (var i = 0; i < emptyInput.length; i++) { 
           $(emptyInput[i]).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-warning')
           if($(emptyInput[i]).val()=='' || $(emptyInput[i]).val()==null){
              var div = $(emptyInput[i]).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-warning')
              return false;
              break;
          }            
      }     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="" method="post" id="UserForm" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iUserName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iUserName" id="iUserName" placeholder="User Name" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="iPassword" id="iPassword" placeholder="iPassword" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iConfPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="iConfPassword" id="iConfPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iRoleSelect" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Role</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select class="form-control select2" id="iRoleSelect" name="iRoleSelect" style="width: 100%;"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: lol sorry i have to delete my previous comment, i didn't notice you add $ before emptyInput

Comment: But irrespective of how many fields you enter the value, all are getting appended with has-warning class right?

Comment: Yes it is fine now

Answer (score 1):

Try using $ sign.
Working Example:

```js
$('#UserForm').on('submit', function () {
        var flag_UserName, flag_Password, flag_Role
        var emptyInput = $('#UserForm').find('input[type=text], input[type=password], select').val('');
        for (var i = 0; i < emptyInput.length; i++) {
            var div = $(emptyInput[i]).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-warning')
            console.log(div)
        }
        return false;
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="UserForm" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iUserName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iUserName" id="iUserName" placeholder="User Name" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="iPassword" id="iPassword" placeholder="iPassword" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iConfPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="iConfPassword" id="iConfPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iRoleSelect" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Role</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select class="form-control select2" id="iRoleSelect" name="iRoleSelect" style="width: 100%;"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```